# Not able to fetch values on views on Jquery ajax post call in Django

Tags: python, django, jquery

On click of button I make Jquery Ajax post call but in the views it is not fetching the values. Here is the code:

jquery:-

```
$("#startSimulator").click(function(){

        test = $("#testRange").val();
        gameKey = ($('input:radio[name=radioGroup]:checked').val() || 0);


        $("#imageLoading").css("display", "block");
        $.post("/blackout/setup/",{d : d,test : test,gameKey : gameKey}, function(data){


            $("#result").append(data);

        });

    });
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
            (r'^blackout/setup/$', 'blackout.views.setup'),
            )
```

views.py:

```
def setup(request):
    gameKey = request.POST['gameKey']
    test = request.POST['test'] 
    data = request.POST['d']

    #Some other code

    #And then HttpResponse(data)
```

Errors:-

```
Exception Value:    
"Key 'gameKey' not found in <QueryDict: {}>"


/home/dhruv/blackout_new_project/blackout/blackout_proj/blackout/views.py in setup
    gameKey = request.POST['gameKey']
```

Comment: I think the problem is with your data dict `{d : d,test : test,gameKey : gameKey}` can you try with this `{'d': d, 'test': test, 'gameKey': gameKey}`

Answer (score 0):

```
    gameKey = ($('input:radio[name=radioGroup]:checked').val() || 0);
```

What is this supposed to do exactly? I think this might be the problem, I'm not sure about radioboxes, but checkboxes return null or undefined (can't remember which one exactly) on their checked attribute if they are not set.

Check the value of gameKey before making the ajax call.

Comment: that's not creating any problem, it gets the value of the checked radio button out of bunch of radio buttons. Problem is the values are not received at the backend (views.py). I have checked that the values are received before making an AJAX call